# How to override parent functions in child themes?

Tags: functions, pluggable, child-theme, parent-theme

I've been reading around and trying to figure out how to do this, but for some reason I can't seem to override parent functions in my child theme.

I'm using TwentyTen as a parent - can anyone tell me why this function in my child theme isn't overriding the parent function please?

```
// Override read more link
function osu_twentyten_continue_reading_link() {
 return ' <a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . __( 'Read on <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten-child' ) . '</a>';
}
function osu_twentyten_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
 return ' &hellip;' . osu_twentyten_continue_reading_link();
}
remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'osu_twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

I thought you had to remove the filter/action etc. before re-adding it right?

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should run the code after theme setup.

```
function osu_twentyten_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . __( 'Read on <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten-child' ) . '</a>';
}

function osu_twentyten_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' &hellip;' . osu_twentyten_continue_reading_link();
}

function my_child_theme_setup() {
    remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'osu_twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Comment: Yep. And the reason it doesn't work directly is that child theme's code is loaded before parent theme's.