# Is it possible to disable a function of a parent theme?

Tags: php, functions, child-theme

I was wondering whether it is possible to completely disable a function that is called in a parent theme's `functions.php` and if so, how? (Of course without deleting the function. Rather by adding something to `functions.php` of the child theme.)

Comment: This question cannot reasonably be answered as-asked. Please post relevant code: in this case, the *actual function definition* of the function in the parent Theme `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only under some circumstances.

1. If the parent theme's functions are wrapped in `function_exists` conditionals then you should be able to replace them. For example:

   ```
   // Parent
   if (!function_exists('p_wpse_95799')) {
     function p_wpse_95799() {
       // 
     }
   }
   ```

   If the child theme defines a function named `p_wpse_95799` then the parent function will not be used. If this is a possibility you'd just need to define a function that does nothing, much like the above.
2. If the function is 'hooked' to some filter or action then you might be able to un-hook it. There is a catch. The child theme `functions.php` loads first which means you may won't be able to [remove filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) directly. You will have to hook them to run after the parent's `functions.php` has ran. Otherwise you will be trying to remove something that has not been added. From the Codex: ["It is also worth noting that you may need to prioritise the removal of the filter to a hook that occurs after the filter is added. You cannot successfully remove the filter before it has been added."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) Mostly this will mean finding a hook that runs after the parent `functions.php` and hooking to that, possibly manipulating the third parameter of [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) or [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to cause your function to run late.

Those are the cases I can think of right now. Perhaps I have forgotten a case. I trust someone will point that out if I have :)

There is no PHP level "remove function" and if you try to define two functions with the same name you will get an error.

As I can't see the code for the function you want to remove, I worry that you are going to break something by removing or altering it, if that is even possible. A little caution is in order.

Answer (score 0):

While it's difficult to know exactly how to do what you want without seeing code, this may help - [How to override parent functions in child themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7557/how-to-override-parent-functions-in-child-themes)

Just ignore the override part of that Q&A if you're not interested in altering the function, and focus on how it goes about removing it.

Basically, you'll want to use use remove_action or remove_filter in your child theme's `function.php` file and run it after the theme has been set up.