# Template files not working with child theme

Tags: child-theme, localhost, local-installation

This is the second week in a row that I'm having trouble trying to get a child theme working with Wordpress, despite having studied the [Codex entry extensively](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and following it word for word.

I'm developing with a local installation using XAMPP.

The parent theme I'm trying to use is called `blocksy`, and it's in the `wp-content/themes` directory. Within that directory, I created another directory  called `industry-road`, and in that created a `style.css` and `functions.php`.

This is the content of the `style.css`:

```
/*!
Theme Name: Industry Road
Author: My Name
Version: 1.0.0
Template: blocksy
Tags: blog, e-commerce, wide-blocks, block-styles, grid-layout, one-column, two-columns, three-columns, four-columns, right-sidebar, left-sidebar, translation-ready, custom-colors, custom-logo, custom-menu, featured-images, footer-widgets, full-width-template, theme-options, threaded-comments
*/
```

And this is the content of `functions.php`:

```
?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'blocksy'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'industry-road',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
?>
```

When I activate the child theme the Wordpress Dashboard does show that it is a child theme of `blocksy`.

However, when I attempt to copy a file `blocksy/inc/hero-section.php` into `industry-road/inc/hero-section.php` (creating the necessary directory structure as I do) and change a line in it, *nothing changes on my site*.

When making the same change to the original `hero-section` file in the parent theme, however, the change takes effect immediately.

In other words, despite the fact that my child theme seems to be activated and working correctly, and despite the fact that the Codex says template files in the child theme should override their equivalent files in the parent theme, this isn't happening.

What exactly is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Yet another perfectly valid, perfectly well-formed question that's been downvoted. It's starting to look like the people on this Stack site resort to voting down questions they're unable to answer.

Comment: The question is not exactly the same as yours, but my answer to it is the same answer I'd give to this question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie So am I correct in thinking that what you're saying is that a "template file" in Wordpress is not any .php file from the parent that has a corresponding file in the child theme, but is a specific list of files that `hero-section.php` is not part of, and that that's the reason why I'm not seeing the changes I make to it?

Comment: Basically, yes. There are certain files, basically the ones on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/), that WordPress loads automatically/. WordPress will load these from child themes. For all other templates the parent theme needs to load them a certain way for that to work. If they don't do that then they can't be replaced.

Comment: Hey @Hashim, one of the Blocksy developers here. There's no way for you to override `blocksy/inc/hero-section.php` file from Blocksy. Ideally, you should be able to override the `blocksy_output_hero_section()` function. 

But, in order to do this, we'd have to declare the function from parent inside a `if (! function_exists('blocksy_output_hero_section')` statement. Don't hesitate to ping me here and I'll assist you further, if you still need help.

More details on the technique here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265328/how-to-override-function-in-child-theme

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu So if I'm correct in understanding you, Blocksy functions are not pluggable by default, but it's possible to make them so by wrapping the function in the parent theme file with `if (! function_exists)`?

Comment: That's true. In fact, I would go as far to say that this method of customisation sounds like very unstable to me. We might decide to refactor the implementation of the hero section, for example, to have a different shape and this would make your changes useless. Can you let me know what exactly what you were trying to customise so that I can further assist you?

Also, you can always write to us via our support channel for any concerns like this one.

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu I agree, it is unstable, because as far as I know any changes I make to the parent theme files would be overwritten as soon as the theme is updated. I decided on Blocksy a while ago for a local non-profit charity and I have to say I'm very impressed with the customisability of it, but is there any particular reason you chose not to implement pluggable functions in Blocksy in order to make it usable as an editable child theme? The only solution I was left with instead of using a child theme was simply to make sure the theme didn't update, because there was no other real choice.

Comment: @Hashim we have a lot of customisability in terms of customiser options. Allowing users to override our functions templates would mean they will not get proper implementation of our options. That is, we haven't yet found a very specific case which would not be possible to solve from the options UI we provide. Even if the hero itself sometimes has limitations, we provide other alternatives. But, please, do not interrupt the updates cycle. As I said, feel free to contact us with a specific case you have in mind and we'll provide detailed instructions.